# How to implement a tensorflow2 layer, tf.nn.conv1d_transpose inside a keras model architecture?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I need to use Transpose Conv1D layer which keras don't have yet , but tensorfow2 does . Till now i can only code in keras. Is there any way to implement a tf.nn.conv1d_transpose layer directly in a keras model along with other keras layers?

Please provide some sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer sample code to add tf.nn.conv1d_transpose inside a keras Sequential model

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x

# Importing dependency
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv1D, MaxPooling1D, Dropout, BatchNormalization, Lambda

# Create a sequential model
model = Sequential()

x=input=[None,256,16]

def conv1d_transpose(x):
    return tf.nn.conv1d_transpose(x, filters=[3.0,8.0,16.0], output_shape=[100, 1024, 8], strides=(4), padding="SAME")

model.add(Conv1D(32,250,padding='same',input_shape=(1500,9)))
model.add(MaxPooling1D(2))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(BatchNormalization())
model.add(Lambda(conv1d_transpose, name='conv1d_transpose'))

# Display Model 
model.summary()
```

Output:

```
Model: "sequential"
    _________________________________________________________________
    Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
    =================================================================
    conv1d (Conv1D)              (None, 1500, 32)          72032     
    _________________________________________________________________
    max_pooling1d (MaxPooling1D) (None, 750, 32)           0         
    _________________________________________________________________
    dropout (Dropout)            (None, 750, 32)           0         
    _________________________________________________________________
    batch_normalization (BatchNo (None, 750, 32)           128       
    _________________________________________________________________
    conv1d_transpose (Lambda)    (100, 1024, 8)            0         
    =================================================================
    Total params: 72,160
    Trainable params: 72,096
    Non-trainable params: 64
    _________________________________________________________________
```